# how to improve OpenCL kernel reading __global char* data efficiently?

Tags: optimization, opencl, motion, mc

1. motion compensation between two images(3840*2160), block size 16
2. kernel divide 3840 * 135(135=2160/16), group size 64*1 or 128*1 (basically no difference)

Now my kernel do access global char data, but `imagepos = src + mv.xy` is not aligned, so must read char one by one. I think there is a latency here, CodeXL also show there is no limited by GPRs. So i need find a method to speed up data read. Also i want to know how to use local memory but data just need once.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: If I understood correctly, Motion Compensation is block matching, so, multiple reads. Local memory can speed a lot your processing.  But without code is difficult to give an answer...

Comment: Hi ZarkZeros, i want to use local memory, but in fact i only use it once, so from global to local,then local to private, is not efficient.
below is my opencl main code.

thanks!

Comment: In fact, my most important problem is to speed up global char data read by aligned reading.

Comment: For optimum read speed of __global char * data, 4 or 8 concurrent work items should read adjacent and aligned data together. Study coalesced reads.